# div hide/show if statements multiple drop boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery

Firstly, this is my first ever time using jQuery, so my code is not going to be the best. I'm adding a filter to my works website based off 3 drop boxes: fuel type, drive-type, and vehicle type. I want that when someone selects petrol it shows all the petrol cars, which I have managed to achieve, but now I'm a bit stuck. I now want it to show based on all 3 boxes, so if someone selects petrol, and then auto and then cars, it will show only petrol automatic cars. I can't seem to make the 3 boxes work together. so please help.

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
$(document).ready(function() {
    // fuels
    $("#fuel").change(function() {
      if ($("#fuel option[value='petrol']").attr('selected')) {
        $('div[class*=petrol]').css('display','block');


      }
          if ($("#fuel option[value='diesel']").attr('selected')) {

        $('div[class*=diesel]').css('display','block'); 


      }
      // end
     //drivetype

    }); 
        $("#drive").change(function() {
      if ($("#drive option[value='man']").attr('selected')) {
        $('div[class*=manual]').css('display','block');


      }
          if ($("#drive option[value='auto']").attr('selected')) {
        $('div[class*=auto]').css('display','block');


      }
      //end


    }); 
    // vech type
    $("#type").change(function() {
      if ($("#type option[value='car']").attr('selected')) {
        $('div[class*=car]').css('display','block');


      }
          if ($("#type option[value='4']").attr('selected')) {
        $('div[class*=4]').css('display','block');


     }

      if ($("#type option[value='7']").attr('selected')) {
        $('div[class*=7]').css('display','block');


     }

     if ($("#type option[value='van']").attr('selected')) {
        $('div[class*=van]').css('display','block');


     }
    // end



    });
  });
```

```
<select id="fuel">
<option value="none">fuel</option>
<option value="petrol">petrol</option>
<option value="diesel">diesel</option>

</select>
<select id="drive">
<option value="none">drive</option>
<option value="man">manual</option>
<option value="auto">auto</option>
</select>
<select id="type">
<option value="none">type</option>
<option value="car">car</option>
<option value="4">4x4</option>
<option value="7">people carrier</option>
<option value="van">van</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically at the time when you want to show the cars, you want to check all 3 select boxes for their values so you know which cars to show

In this case when showing cars for "auto" you need to check petrol as well as auto. when showing cars for "cars" you need to check all 3.

edit:

```
$("#type").change(function() {
    // check previous select box value, check this box value
    // output the correct cars
});
```

for the last one you simply check both of the previous boxes and this box and output the correct cars

Comment: I know thats what i want to do, but i dont know how to do it. thanks

Comment: you dunno the code itself or you dunno the logic of it? if you dunno code then google what you need to know or look at the jquery doc. I am at work and don't have time to write up the entire block

Answer (score 0):

Try to do something like:

```
 $("#fuel").change(function() {
   var value = $(this).val();

   $(".elements_to_hide").hide(); //check if needed

   $("." + value).show();

});
```

Please don`t take it personally, but I`ll give some suggestions about your code:

1. Try to avoid such complex constractions like: $('div[class*=diesel]').[It will affect the performance](http://paulirish.com/2009/perf/).
2. JQuery contains build-in functions for show/hide DOM elements — .show(), .hide()
3. To get selected option of "select" use .val();

Hope answer will helpful for you. Best regards!

Comment: Yeah, first time ive used jquery so still a bit lost, ive tried you code but i cant even get it to fire the script, what am i doing wrong ?

Comment: I made some edition to my answer. Likely you need to replace ".elements_to_hide" with your own.

Comment: Getting pretty close now, how do i do it so that its hides the value thats not selected, eg if its petrol selected how do i change
    $(".elements_to_hide").hide(); to hide the unslected value